# Parsing Through Telephone Numbers Parse swift

Tags: swift, parsing, contacts

In my app I save the user's phone numbers they give me so others can find them and they can find their contacts on the app. But I am having trouble parsing through the phone numbers because users can save phone numbers in different ways:

– Country code, area code, number: +1 (area code) xxx-xxxx

– Country code, number: +1 xxx-xxxx

– Number: xxx-xxxx

The way I save the users number is by adding the area code and number as one long number and save the country code separately. I tried parsing through the telephone numbers taken from Contacts to mimic how I saved the numbers but it does not work. Is there something I am missing? I have copied the code at the bottom:

```
    if accessGranted {
                    let contactStore = CNContactStore()
                    let keys = [CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]
                    let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys as [CNKeyDescriptor])
                    do {
                        try contactStore.enumerateContacts(with: request, usingBlock: { (contact, error) in
                            let phoneNumberRaw = contact.phoneNumbers.first?.value.stringValue ?? ""

                            var phoneNumberRawArray = phoneNumberRaw.components(separatedBy: " ")
                            var phoneString = ""
                            if phoneNumberRawArray.count >= 3 { //probably has country code in the front
                                //remove country code
                                phoneNumberRawArray.removeFirst()
                            }

                            //add to phone string
                            for phone in phoneNumberRawArray {
                                phoneString.append(phone)
                            }
                            phoneString = phoneString.replacingOccurrences(of: "(", with: "")
                            phoneString = phoneString.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
                            phoneString = phoneString.replacingOccurrences(of: ")", with: "")
                            phoneString = phoneString.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")



                             self.contactsPhoneNumbers.append(phoneString)    

                                //get country code
                                for ContactNumber:CNLabeledValue in contact.phoneNumbers
                            {
                                let fullNumber  = ContactNumber.value
                                let countryCode = fullNumber.value(forKey: "countryCode") as? String
                                self.contactsCountryCode.append(countryCode!)
                            }

                        })
                    }
                    catch {
                        print("Unable to get contacts")
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Keep in mind that there are hundreds of phone number formats around the world. Don't assume typical US/Canada phone numbers.

Comment: Well, since the users are giving you their numbers you can have your own database to check against others. What I mean is that you can set a pattern like country code + area + number. Yes, you still won't be able to work 100% with the users' contacts but the ones using your app will be there.